# KafkaConsumer.commitAsync() behavior with a lower offset than previous

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, offset, spring-kafka

How will kafka deal with a call to

`KafkaConsumer.commitAsync(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets, OffsetCommitCallback callback)`

when offset value for a topic is given as a lesser value than a previous invocation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will simply set the offset of the partition to the value you specified,so next time you will consume you message from commitedOffset+1.
The javadoc of `commitAsync()` says:

> The committed offset should be the next message your application will consume,i.e. lastProcessedMessageOffset + 1.

Answer (score 4):

I was curious and tested it to see the behavior. As written in the docs, it is correct what @haoyuwang wrote in his answer (+1).

The reason behind it is quite simple. The committed offsets of a consumer group are stored in Kafka within the internal topic `__consumer_offsets`. This topic is `compact` which means it is meant to provide the latest value for a given key. In your case the key is a combination of the Consumer Group, Topic and partition whereas your value is the offset.

If you now

- commit offset 10 and due to asynchronous process later
- commit offset 5

offset 5 will be the latest value in the `__consumer_offsets` topic. That means the next offset your consumer will read from that topic partition is offset 6 and not offset 11.

#### How to reproduce

You could simply reproduce it and test it by (synchronously) commit an earlier offset after your regular commit, like this:

```java
consumer.commitSync();
consumer.commitSync(commitFirstMessage);
```

where `commitFirstMessage` is defined as

```java
TopicPartition zeroTopicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
OffsetAndMetadata zeroOffset = new OffsetAndMetadata(0L);

Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> commitFirstMessage = new HashMap<>();
commitFirstMessage.put(zeroTopicPartition, zeroOffset);
```

---

EDIT:

#### How to avoid committing lower offsets with commitAsync

In the book [Kafka - The Definitive Guide](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide/) there is a recommendation to avoid commit lower offsets because of a retrying call of `commitAsync`:

> **Retrying Async Commits**: A simple pattern to get commit order right for asynchronous retries is to use a monotonically increasing sequence number. Increase the sequence number every time you commit and add the
> sequence number at the time of the commit to the commitAsync callback. When you’re getting ready to send a retry, check if the commit sequence number the callback got is equal to the instance variable; if it is, there was no newer commit and it is safe to retry. If the instance sequence number is higher, don’t retry because a newer commit was already sent.

An implementation could look like this (not actually tested!):

```scala
import java.util._
import java.time.Duration
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerConfig, ConsumerRecord, KafkaConsumer, OffsetAndMetadata, OffsetCommitCallback}
import org.apache.kafka.common.{KafkaException, TopicPartition}
import collection.JavaConverters._

object AsyncCommitWithCallback extends App {

  // define topic
  val topic = "myOutputTopic"

  // set properties
  val props = new Properties()
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "AsyncCommitter5")
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
  // [set more properties...]
  

  // create KafkaConsumer and subscribe
  val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
  consumer.subscribe(List(topic).asJavaCollection)

  // initialize global counter
  val atomicLong = new AtomicLong(0)

  // consume message
  try {
    while(true) {
      val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1)).asScala

      if(records.nonEmpty) {
        for (data <- records) {
          // do something with the records
        }
        consumer.commitAsync(new KeepOrderAsyncCommit)
      }

    }
  } catch {
    case ex: KafkaException => ex.printStackTrace()
  } finally {
    consumer.commitSync()
    consumer.close()
  }


  class KeepOrderAsyncCommit extends OffsetCommitCallback {
    // keeping position of this callback instance
    val position = atomicLong.incrementAndGet()

    override def onComplete(offsets: util.Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata], exception: Exception): Unit = {
      // retrying only if no other commit incremented the global counter
      if(exception != null){
        if(position == atomicLong.get) {
          consumer.commitAsync(this)
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```