# Why do Kafka Consumers lose their data?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka Consumer was unable to complete the work normally due to a database problem while working. After that, the state of the database returned to normal.

Messages received while there was a problem with the database were lost. Why Kafka couldn't process data normally due to a database problem, but the offset was shifted?

For example, while receiving a message from offset 10 to offset 100, the database was operating abnormally, and the database operated normally from 101, but the offset operates from 101 and data from 10 to 100 is lost. ack mode is manual

Comment: Do you send the ack for messages managed while the database is working abnormally?

Comment: Consumers don't maintain state, so there's no data to lose... You mean the topic lost data?

Answer (score 0):

The offset position of every KafkaConsumer (to be more precisely: every ConsumerGroup) is stored in an internal Kafka topic `__consumer_offsets`. In this topic the deletion policy is set to `compact` which means it eventually keeps the information about the last committed offset.

Now, as it happened in your case, if the consumer failed to commit the messages 10 to 100 but then commits the message 101, you Kafka consumer will continue to consume messages with offset 102 and will *not* try to read again messages 10 to 100.

As far as Kafka is informed about the offset position of your ConsumerGroup, there is no difference if you

A) **Do not** commit messages 10 to 100 but then commit 101

B) **Do** commit messages 10 to 100 and then commit 101.

I have explained this behavior in bit more detailed in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63740084/kafkaconsumer-commitasync-behavior-with-a-lower-offset-than-previous/63742103#63742103)